# How to spread out the letters a little bit when using text decoration?

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations, letterspacing

The default text-decoration letters look a little bit squished together:

[image]

I can manually make them the way I want by changing `gather` to

```
g{\kern1pt a}{\kern1pt t}{\kern1pt h}{\kern1pt e}{\kern1pt r}{}
```

but this is tedious and annoying. (more so for longer decorations)

Is there an automatic method of tweaking all the letters apart?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm ] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|gather},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm ] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|g{\kern1pt a}{\kern1pt t}{\kern1pt h}{\kern1pt e}{\kern1pt r}{}},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `microtype`'s `\lsstyle` would be a possibility

Comment: how do I find out more information on that?

Comment: @Robert I confirm that `text={|\lsstyle\sffamily|gather}` does the job; can you write an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `text effects along path` option of the `decorations.text` library. I increased the gap, you can manage it by changing the `character widths={inner xsep=1pt}` option.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
                text effects along path,
                text={gather},
                text align=center,
                raise=0.2cm,
                text effects/.cd,
                characters={ text along path,font=\bf\sffamily},
                character widths={inner xsep=1pt}}]
\draw[->,cyan!50!white,text=black,line width=1.5mm,
preaction={decorate} ]
 (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is! The best answer so far which exploit all options for decorate text. +1!

Comment: @Zarko Thanks you :_)

Comment: @Zarko Also for me ...all answer are +1..also the answer of  AndréC that use the specific code of TikZ and not like me when I use Mathcha. 

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to achieve is called letterspacing, and one possibility would be to use the `microtype` package: It provides the commands `\textls[<letterspacing amount>]{<text>}` and `\lsstyle`. Since it doesn't seem to be possible to typeset text in the decoration if it appears inside an argument (or at least I couldn't find out how), only the latter can be used here:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm ] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\lsstyle|gather},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm ] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|g{\kern1pt a}{\kern1pt t}{\kern1pt h}{\kern1pt e}{\kern1pt r}{}},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

The letterspacing amount can be modified with the `letterspace` package option:

```
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}
```

where the number denotes thousandths of an `em`, so in this case 0.15em (the default is 0.1em). To change the letterspacing amount locally, you could define a new command:

```
\newcommand\ltsp[1]{\expandafter\def\csname MT@letterspace@\endcsname{#1}\lsstyle}
```

and use it like this: `text={|\sffamily\ltsp{400}|gather}`.

(Note that letterspacing with `microtype` works with pdflatex or lualatex, but not with xelatex.)

Comment: (i) does all fonts support `microtype`? If i remebrer correcztly not;  (ii) how to set `letterspace=150` locally, for example for this decoration only?

Comment: @Zarko it works with all fonts with pdflatex and lualatex, see my edit

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice answer +1!

Answer (score 4):

Here I create a `tokcycle` package macro `\spaceouttext{gap}{text}` that, when invoked, creates the desired tokens in the package's token register named `\cytoks`.  Thus, do the invocation prior to the `\draw` and pass `\the\cytoks` as the textual argument.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tokcycle}
\newcommand\spaceouttext[2]{%
  \tokcycle{\addcytoks{##1{\kern#1}}}%
  {\processtoks{##1}}%
  {\addcytoks{##1}}%
  {\addcytoks{##1{\kern#1}}}{#2}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\spaceouttext{4pt}{gather}
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm ] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|\the\cytoks},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very intrigue solution. So far I wasn't aware for `tokcycle` ... I install it to my MikTeX with console, however testing your MWE gives error  `I can't find file `tokcycle.tex'.`. Where is this file? I have recent (upgraded just now) MikTeX.

Comment: @Zarko Miktex does not load the package properly, despite my efforts to communicate with them.  Because the package runs in both LaTeX and plain TeX, the `tokcycle.sty` file should go in `tex/latex/tokcycle`, whereas `tokcycle.tex` should go in `tex/generic/tokcycle`.  The files + documentation are available at `https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle`

Comment: Thank you for the info. That is pity, otherwise MikTeX is good maintained  Hopefully this will be resolved soon. I will read documentation on the my first spare time.